# 4-sum algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

I am trying to find whether a list has 4 elements that sum to 0 (and later find what those elements are). I'm trying to make a solution based off the `even k` algorithm described at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem.

I get this code in Python using `combinations` from the standard library

```
def foursum(arr):
  seen = {sum(subset) for subset in combinations(arr,2)}
  return any(-x in seen for x in seen)
```

But this fails for input like [-1, 1, 2, 3]. It fails because it matches the sum (-1+1) with itself. I think this problem will get even worse when I want to find the elements because you can separate a set of 4 distinct items into 2 sets of 2 items in 6 ways: {1,4}+{-2,-3}, {1,-2}+{4,-3} etc etc.

How can I make an algorithm that correctly returns all solutions avoiding this problem?
EDIT: I should have added that I want to use as efficient algorithm as possible. O(len(arr)^4) is too slow for my task...

Comment: May be it's worth asking (commenting) in the mentioned topic, i.e. http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem?

Comment: Since I am new I cannot comment there otherwise I would

Comment: I believe the answer in the linked thread is flawed, as it may return the same element twice (unless I misunderstood something). For example, in `[2,1,-2,2]` - you will get the list `[2,-4,4,-2,2,-4]` - now, choosing -4,4 will get you the elements (-2,2) and (2,2) - but you don't have the element 2 three times.

Comment: Also, since you want ALL solutions, the problem is `O(n^4)` - since the output might be of this size. Take an example of `[-1]*(n/2).extend([1]*(n/2))`. you need to "choose" two instances of -1 w/o repeats - `(n/2)*(n/2-1)` possibilities, and 2 instances of 1 w/o repeats - `(n/2)*(n/2-1)` possibilities. This totals in `(n/2)*(n/2-1)*(n/2)*(n/2-1)` which is in `Theta(n^4)`

Comment: The solution given is wrong. For example a list like [2,-1,-3,10000] will give zero since, 2+(-1) and (-3,2) will give 0

Answer (score 2):

This works.

import itertools

```
def foursum(arr):
  seen = {}
  for i in xrange(len(arr)):
      for j in xrange(i+1,len(arr)):
          if arr[i]+arr[j] in seen: seen[arr[i]+arr[j]].add((i,j))
          else: seen[arr[i]+arr[j]] = {(i,j)}
  for key in seen:
      if -key in seen:
          for (i,j) in seen[key]:
              for (p,q) in seen[-key]:
                  if i != p and i != q and j != p and j != q:
                      return True
  return False
```

**EDIT**
This can be made more pythonic i think, I don't know enough python.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the problem is `O(n^4)` in worst case, since the output size might be of `O(n^4)` (you are looking for finding all solutions, not only the binary problem).

**Proof:**

Take an example of `[-1]*(n/2).extend([1]*(n/2))`. you need to "choose" two instances of -1 w/o repeats - `(n/2)*(n/2-1)/2` possibilities, and 2 instances of 1 w/o repeats - `(n/2)*(n/2-1)/2` possibilities. This totals in `(n/2)*(n/2-1)*(n/2)*(n/2-1)/4` which is in `Theta(n^4)`

Now, that we understood we cannot achieve `O(n^2logn)` worst case, we can get to the following algorithm (pseudo-code), that should scale closer to `O(n^2logn)` for "good" cases (few identical sums), and get `O(n^4)` worst case (as expected).

**Pseudo-code:**

```
subsets <- all subsets of size of indices (not values!)
l <- empty list
for each s in subsets:
   #appending a triplet of (sum,idx1,idx2):
   l.append(( arr[s[0]] + arr[s[1]], s[0],s[1]))
sort l by first element (sum) in each tupple
for each x in l:
    binary search l for -x[0] #for the sum
    for each element y that satisfies the above:
          if x[1] != y[1] and x[2] != y[1] and x[1] != y[2] and x[2] != y[2]:
              yield arr[x[1]], arr[x[2]], arr[y[1]], arr[y[2]]
```

Probably a pythonic way to do the above will be more elegant and readable, but I am not a python expert I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for the 4SUM problem to permit input elements to be used multiple times. For instance, given the input (2 3 1 0 -4 -1), valid solutions are (3 1 0 -4) and (0 0 0 0).

The basic algorithm is O(n^2): Use two nested loops, each running over all the items in the input, to form all sums of pairs, storing the sums and their components in some kind of dictionary (hash table, AVL tree). Then scan the pair-sums, reporting any quadruple for which the negative of the pair-sum is also present in the dictionary.

If you insist on not duplicating input elements, you can modify the algorithm slightly. When computing the two nested loops, start the second loop beyond the current index of the first loop, so no input elements are taken twice. Then, when scanning the dictionary, reject any quadruples that include duplicates.

I discuss this problem at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/08/14/4sum/), where you will see solutions in multiple languages, including Python.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Ofcourse the algorithm shall be atleast as time complex as per the solution size!**

If the number of possible solutions is not 'large' as compared to n, then

A suggested solution in O(N^3):

Find pair-wise sums of all elements and build a NxN matrix of the sums.

For each element in this matrix, build a struct that would have sumValue, row and column as it fields.

Sort all these `N^2` struct elements in a 1D array. `(in O(N^2 logN) time)`.

For each element `x` in this array, conduct a binary search for its partner `y` such that `x + y = 0 (O(logn) per search)`.

Now if you find a partner `y`, check if its row or column field matches with the element `x`. If so, iterate sequentially in both directions until either there is no more such y.

If you find some y's that do not have a common row or column with x, then increment the count (or print the solution).

This iteration can at most take `2N` steps because the length of rows and columns is `N`.

Hence the total order of complexity for this algorithm shall be `O(N^2 * N) = O(N^3)`